# Radbutton Onclick mozilla bug

Tags: telerik, mozilla

When i click a radbutton then postback changing page url as /blabla.aspx?**btnMsg_ClientState=&btnCarDetails=Sorgula&btnCarDetails_ClientState=&btnPrice_ClientState=&btnReject_ClientState=#** ..

First pop-up work but then break.

There are 5 extra buttons and seems all in page url. Where is coming these query strings ?

Ie Developer tools says:

ScriptResource.axd...

I cant find solution, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the form on your page is configured to use a **GET** request when submitted.

`<form id="form1" runat="server" method="get">`

In this case all parameters on the page are specified as part of the URL, which includes the input elements that are used for rendering the button, as well as the other input elements on your page.

You can change this behavior by setting the **method** attribute of the form to **post**, so that a **POST** request is utilized for submitting the form.

`<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">`

In this case the parameters will be passed in the message body of the HTTP request.